# R table1 within furniture package

Tags: r, latex

I am trying to create a latex based table1 using the following variables.
However, whenever I run the code, I get the error pasted below. I have attempted several times to load packages that include the magrittr pipe (including dplyr, tidyr, magrittr) but the error still appears. Does anyone have any experience with this package?

Code:

```r
library(furniture)
table1(tb_table1,
      SEX, AGE, RACE)
```

> Error: Error in selecting(data.frame(.data, stringsAsFactors = TRUE), ...) %>%  :
> object 'magrittr_pipe' not found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it simply by updating both packages.